# Namespace or type can't be found

Tags: c#, class, compiler-errors

I have a program consisting of three classes. When I put the classes in the same file I can compile and run the code just fine. When I put each class in a separate file I get error CS0246 "The type or namespace could not be found" when I try to make objects of the two non-main method classes. I am not using namespaces, and the files are in the same folder.

I am not using Visual Studio. I compile the code in the command line. (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

If you are separating the classes into different files you will need to 'import' the classes with **using** statements (typically if they have a namespace).

Try implementing using statements with just the class names, else I would highly recommend using namespaces (the same namespace is preferable in this scenario) in conjunction with using statements

Comment: I tried importing them using "using" in conjunction with a common namespace. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Did you ensure its not a already taken namespace like 'System' (the .NET namespace), Ensure you create your own namespace....ie.  namespace MyProjects { //Insert code here }

Comment: I found out the problem. I am supposed to type the name of alle the source files in the command line. I come from a Java background and there I don't need to. But thanks for the help man.